# Let $ n > 1 $. Show that there exists a proper subgroup $ H $ of $ S_{n} $ such that $ [S_n : H] \leq n. $

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups

> Let $ n > 1 $. Show that there exists a proper subgroup $ H $ of $ S_{n} $ such that $ [S_n : H] \leq n. $

From what i learn i can only deduce that $[S_n:H] = \frac{|S_n|}{|H|}$ because $S_n$ and $H$ is finite so its a consequence of Lagrange. And since $|S_n| = n!$, $|H|$ divides $n!$.

From then i can't seem to get to the problem. Please help.

Comment: Hint: Rather than applying the abstract theory, think of concrete subgroups of the symmetric group. For example, are you familiar with the sign of a permutation?

Comment: Do you mean the sgn notation?

Comment: if $S_n$ is a permutation group then a subgroup of even permutations $A_n$ immediately helps us as $[S_n : A_n] = 2$.

Comment: Also $S_{n-1}$ lives in $S_n$, one copy of $S_{n-1}$ can be identified as the subgroup of $S_n$ which keeps the $n$ fixed.